# How to make Protractor print passing tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

As the title says really! You can make rspec print passing tests, instead of just any failing ones; is there a way to make Protractor do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which testing framework you're using. Protractor supports Mocha, Cucumber and Jasmine (the default option). If you're using Jasmine, you can change a few things in your protractor config file to change how Jasmine behaves with the `jasmineNodeOptions` object, but you want to customize the console output. For that you need a **reporter**. If you integrate something like [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) into your project, you can customize your console output, including displaying passing specs.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking about having a *detailed jasmine console reporter*.

We've been successfully using `TerminalReporter` reporter from the  [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) package. Install the package and add the following to `onPrepare()`:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TerminalReporter({
    verbosity: 3,
    color: true,
    showStack: true
}));
```